# PerfMon template for %Processor Time for a given process

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, perfmon

I want to get CPU/%Processor time for my process "MyCustomProcess.exe", I added the counter in the template but I do not get the counter in PerfMon data collector set.

Custom_PerfMon_template:

I get _Total % Processor Time

```
<Counter>\Process(_Total)\% Processor Time</Counter>
```

I also get this value:

```
<CounterDisplayName>\.NET CLR Exceptions(MyCustomProcess)\# of Exceps Thrown</CounterDisplayName>
```

I do **not** get this value:

```
<Counter>\Process(MyCustomProcess)\% Processor Time</Counter>
```

How can I get "\Process(MyCustomProcess)\% Processor Time" value?

Thanks, 
RDV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, counters are there, just not shown.
Solution:

1. Open the *.blg file in PerfMon
2. In Bottom section, right click-> Add Counters
3. Select the counter you want to add and click Add.
4. Counter should be displayed now.

Just do not understand, `why it doesn't show the counters by default.`
Similar issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/193042/perfmon-counters-can-be-selected-but-dont-display-data

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks,
RDV